# Scribble Maps set map options Latitude Longituude

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set map options Latitude and Longitude to Scribble Maps. I'm sure it can be done the same way as google maps but can't find more info in the documentation. This is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var sm = new scribblemaps.ScribbleMap(document.getElementById('ScribbleMap'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var sm = new scribblemaps.ScribbleMap(document.getElementById('ScribbleMap'), {startCenter: [0,0]});
});
```